# how to use two outputs in library

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I was wondering if it is possible to have more that one outputs in the pinescript library?
For example is the following code valid?

```
export sorting_float(float[] Value, int[] BarIndex) => //{
    var NewBarInd = array.new_int()
    ValueSorted = array.copy(Value)
    sortedLowsIndices = array.sort_indices(Value) 
    array.sort(ValueSorted, order.ascending)
    Size = array.size(BarIndex)
    if Size>0
        for i = 0 to Size-1
            array.push(NewBarInd,array.get(BarIndex,array.get(sortedLowsIndices,i)))
    ValueSorted, NewBarInd
```

where `ValueSorted, NewBarInd` are supposed to be outputs...

Also if the above situation is resolved, how should I get the outputs in the main code?
I see that the following code gives me error:

```
float[] output_1, int[] ouput_2 = mylib.sorting_float(Input_1, Input_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions can return a `tuple` by using `[]`:

```
export sorting_float(float[] Value, int[] BarIndex) => //{
    var NewBarInd = array.new_int()
    ValueSorted = array.copy(Value)
    sortedLowsIndices = array.sort_indices(Value) 
    array.sort(ValueSorted, order.ascending)
    Size = array.size(BarIndex)
    if Size>0
        for i = 0 to Size-1
            array.push(NewBarInd,array.get(BarIndex,array.get(sortedLowsIndices,i)))
    [ValueSorted, NewBarInd]
```

Then you can call the function and receive a tuple using the same method:

```
[output_1, ouput_2] = mylib.sorting_float(Input_1, Input_2)
```